# Is Google Apps Script SaaS or PaaS?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform

I'm a beginner with Google Apps Script and I would like to know that if that is Software as a Service or Platform as a Service. Thank you for your explanation.

Answer (score -1):

This whole google cloud is a platform as a service as you are getting the full cloud for processing your scripts and whole data as a platform